# I have made a slide show in javascript but I don't know how to make my pics faze

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

My slideshow I've made with javascript changes the pictures really fast. I want to stop them from flashing to the next one and instead include more javascript to make the pics change slowly.

I looked this up on stackoverflow and others seem to use JQuery or something which I didn't understand too well. Is there any chance I could add some kind of delay to my javascript?

Here's what I have:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var pics = new Array(10);
    pics[0] = "images/pic1.jpg";
    pics[1] = "images/pic2.jpg";
    pics[2] = "images/pic3.jpg";
    pics[3] = "images/pic4.jpg";
    pics[4] = "images/pic5.jpg";
    pics[5] = "images/pic6.jpg";
    pics[6] = "images/pic7.jpg";


    var c = 0;
    var timer = 0;

    function cyclePics() {

        document.getElementById("pic1").src = pics[c];
        c++;
        if (c == 7) {
            c = 0;
        }
        timer = setTimeout("cyclePics()", 2000);
    }
</script>

</head>

<body onLoad="cyclePics()"> 

<div>

<img src="images/pic1.jpg" id="pic1"/>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Google javascript image fade.  There's lots of code on the web to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres what you can do without using a library such as JQuery. It´s pure CSS/Javascript.

You can read something on the internet about the transition animations. With transition you can make sure that a CSS-Property changes very slowly. For example you could do.

```
function nextImg(){                         
    diaimg.style.opacity ="0";
    window.setTimeout (
    function(){
        diaimg.style.opacity ="1";
        document.images["urOBJ"].src = urArray[imgnr].src;
        imgnr++;
        if (imgnr>9){imgnr = 1;}
        }, 500);  // u can play a bit with this delay
}
function slider(){                     //nextIMG will be called every 2000ms
    IntervalID = setInterval("nextImg()", 2000);
}
```

This will first make the picure transparent, then define a new image, and then again move the opacity to 1. Now if u want it to be smooth you should include the CSS Code:

```
    opacity: 1; transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
```

It´s not super fancy but it works.
If you want something better, you should read this article:
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

If you really understand how this works you can do slide-In/Out effects aswell as Fade-In/Out effects

Answer (score 1):

jQuery makes this stuff easy.

```
function cyclePics() {

        $("#pic"+c).animate({opacity:0}, 2000, function(){
            c++;
            if (c == 7) {
                c = 0;
            }
            document.getElementById("pic1").src = pics[c];
             $("#pic"+c).animate({opacity:1}, 2000, function(){ setTimeout(cyclePics, 2000) });
        })


    }
```

This code uses jQuery's animate method. You can use the call back functions to time stuff so it happens at the end of an animation.

Here's how it happens in order.

1. Fade #pic1 to 0 opacity
2. evaluate C and change the src of #pic1
3. fade #pic1 back in
4. setTimeout to call cyclePics again.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a plugin for javascript that allows you to do all kinds of things, ranging from animation to manipulating html elements easily. In your case, jQuery is the way to go.

Add this to your html page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then go find a jQuery tutorial, and do yourself a favor and learn it thoroughly. Focus on the `animate()` function. jQuery alone should be all you need, but there are also some other extensions that make slideshows even easier. For example, [slidesjs](http://slidesjs.com/)